# how to setup 404 Not found page in Flutter using Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-hosting

I am trying to show a custom 404 not found page in my website with Flutter.

I am using the following code :

```
MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        initialRoute: "/",
        routes: {
          "/": (context) => Scaffold(),
          "/test": (context) => TestPage()
        },
        onUnknownRoute: (settings) {
          return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Text("Page not found !"),
            ),
          ));
        },
```

i have rebuild my app and deploy it with Firebase Hosting. However i am seeing this if i enter a wrong url :

[image]

Since i am using flutter, i don't really want to add an .html file as it is said, even if it works.
I would rather display a custom page built in dart.

How can i display my custom "Page not found" in such case ?

**EDIT** :

Here is my current `firebase.json` file :

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "public": "build/web",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What i have tried and what didn't work :

- Not having rewrites
- Having rewrites in hope that flutter routing would take the lead
- Test the project in localhost
- Change the Flutter routing Strategy from URL to PATH according to the [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/navigation/url-strategies)

In the end :

- My existing pages in the website are working fine
- All wrong urls are redirected to /index.html

The only thing that is working is :

- Adding a 404.html file in my /build/web folder
- Remove rewrites in `firebase.json`

However this is not what i want, i would like to display my not_found_page.dart instead.

This might be a Flutter issue, i keep this open in the meantime but i will dig deeper on the Flutter side.

Comment: Try using other device... the older version may be cached. Can you share the URL so anyone here can test it out, if possible ?

Comment: I have tested on Chrome and Safari, clearing the cache in both first :/ and on another computer too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was indeed on the Flutter side.
I was using "/" as `initialRoute` and "/" as another route which was creating conflicts apparently and was actually useless in my code as the first page returned is defined under the `MaterialApp`'s `child`.

Flutter was redirecting my routes to `"/"` instead of calling `onUnknownRoute` and there was a conflict with the rewrites in firebase.json

So i have removed the `"/": (context) => Scaffold(),` from the `routes` map.
I have also removed `rewrites` in `firebase.json` in order for this to work.

I have also set back the `URL` strategy, all the steps above were not working with the `PATH` strategy.

**EDIT** : i have figured out that the `PATH` strategy can work only if there is no `home` property on the `MaterialApp` widget.
If so, all of the wrong routes will be redirected to the `home` and not call the `onUnknownRoute`

> - For the / route, the home property, if non-null, is used.

> - Otherwise, the routes table is used, if it has an entry for the route.

> - Otherwise, onGenerateRoute is called, if provided. It should return a non-null value for any valid route not handled by home and routes.

> - Finally if all else fails onUnknownRoute is called.

PS : There is no need to implement `404.html` file

Answer (score 0):

just add a 404.html page in your root and redirect it your own custom flutter built page.
you can also learn to handle the

> **'Famous 404 page not found !' from [here](https://www.didierboelens.com/2020/02/flutter-web-404-direct-url-no-hash/)**

Comment: I have tried it but still doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: You need to modify your firebase json rules for hosting to support that

Comment: "I have tried it but still doesn't work unfortunately" Edit your question to show what you've done please.

Comment: I have edited the question with all of my tests and results, what do you mean @austin by "redirect it your own custom flutter built page" ? How can i do that please ?

Comment: hey @Tom3652 , i have edited my answer and i believe that the given link might help you to solve your problem

Comment: Very nice article, i will probably use it to hide the "#" symbol without switching back to the ```PathUrlStrategy``` (which hides the # by default). I am also creating an issue about it in the Flutter repo to tell that it prevents the call to ```onUnknownRoute```.